# (FreeSWITCH) [ERR] mod_event_socket.c:2992 Socket Error! Could not listen on 127.0.0.1:8021

Tags: freeswitch, bigbluebutton

I'm getting following error in `freeswitch.log` file while connecting microphone in BigBlueButton 2.4.9 meeting.

```
[ERR] mod_event_socket.c:2992 Socket Error! Could not listen on 127.0.0.1:8021
```

I'm not able to connect audio in the meeting. When I attempt to connect with a microphone it goes to Audio Test then says Establishing audio connection... it never passes this point. I tried letting it wait, and it just doesn't connect.

- I have set the following in `event_socket.conf.xml`.

```
<param name="listen-ip" value="127.0.0.1"/>
```

- Below is the configurations for FreeSWITCH in `default.yml` file:

```
freeswitch:
  ip: <internal_IPv4>
  sip_ip: <extarnal_IPv4>
  port: 5066
  esl_ip: 127.0.0.1
  esl_port: 8021
  handleExternalConnections: false
```

- The output of `netstat -ant | grep 5060` is as per below:

```
tcp        0      0 <internal_IPv4>:5060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

- The output of `netstat -vatupn | grep 8021` is as per below:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)

Comment: what have you for this entry in <param name="nat-map" value="false"/>, try setting it to the opposite and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. Apparently, for some reason, my ip address had changed>
If you check your ip address using . Try changing the 127.0.0.1 to the ip address and all should be fine